# JSON-RPC ERC20 transfer

Tags: web3js, erc-20, json-rpc

I'm using JSON-RPC sendTransaction, I want to transfer the ERC20 token this way, the code above works fine, but surprisingly, instead of calling `transfer()`, a contract is deployed for me!!It's really weird, I wonder what I missed?

This is the result of code execution:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x96f4a4c00a81678f3d32855d05894f3ea9f667970ef0f7a042496b77e3e5e9fb

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const data= ADToken.methods.transfer("0x0325E8d42da1FA8Ed7e43dFC3D2c99A31605f838",this.web3.utils.toWei("1000")).encodeABI();

        const gasPrice = await this.web3.eth.getGasPrice();

        const tx = {
            from: this.connector.session.accounts[0],
            to: ADToken.options.address,
            data: data,
            gasPrice: this.web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
            gas: this.web3.utils.toHex(90000),
        };

        console.log('tx', tx);

        this.connector.sendTransaction(tx)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('result', result);

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error' + error);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/issues/2744

I found the answer on Gitub, and it's a very serious metamask bug that hasn't been fixed yet!